# estudio does not check `require` when it should?

Tags: eiffel, design-by-contract, eiffel-studio-19.12

Eiffel Studio seems to pass through my requirements even if I have them enabled on project settings. And as far as I remember I was able some time to put a break point into the requirements...

I don't understand what I'am missing here, as you can see in my example, the requirement passes through as I have the same condition on the code and it goes into (`attached {POWER_DEVICE} a_csv.device as l_dev`).

[image]

Comment: What should `require TRUE` tell the user about the contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general rule for inherited assertions is the following:

- preconditions can be only relaxed;
- postconditions can be only strengthened.

In the particular example the effective precondition is

```
    True
or else
    valid_csv (a_csv) and then attached {POWER_DEVICE} a_csv.device
```

This is reflected by the keywords `require` at the beginning and `require else` in the middle of the combined precondition in the flat form of the feature. The expression `True` is inherited. This is the precondition of the feature in the parent.

A possible solution is to move `valid_csv (a_csv)` to the parent feature, and redefine `valid_csv` in the descendant. If `valid_csv` is common for all calls, but the second test varies across descendants, it might be better to introduce a new feature `is_known` and have 2 precondition subclauses in the parent:

```
is_valid_csv: is_valid_csv (a_csv)
is_known_csv: is_known_csv (a_csv)
```

The implementation of `is_known_csv` in the class `POWER_CSV_PROCESSOR` would be

```
is_known_csv (a_csv: ...)
    do
        Result := attached {POWER_DEVICE} a_csv.device
    end
```

and the precondition of feature `process` in `POWER_CSV_PROCESSOR` would be empty.

The caller would then do something like

```
if processor.is_known_csv (csv) then
    processor.process (csv)
end
```

Comment: Many thx, discovering everyday some `I thought it was...` is there a place I can find the semantic of require else? I wrote it so many times without even thinking about its semantic in fact

Comment: @Pipo Most information is available online. For example, feature contracts and inheritance is discussed at [eiffel.org](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/uuid/c90e6ee3-b39d-48e5-2321-a34e12fd5327#Inheritance_and_contracts). For offline reading, I would go for Object-Oriented Software Construction 2nd edition. It's a bit outdated and does not reflect most recent Eiffel capabilities like [tag:void-safety] or SCOOP. However, it gives good background on the general ideas of object-oriented programming, [tag:design-by-contract], etc.